# how to make the configuration .emacs to be global in linux

Tags: linux, emacs

what I mean is that I've had a .emacs file in my /home,but when I cd ,for example,/etc/profile,the configurations which are written in the .emacs make no sense.So I want to know how to make the .emacs  to be global. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file `default.el` and put it in one of the standard library search directories (/usr/share/lib, /usr/local/lib).

You should first check you LD_LIBRARY_PATH to find the search path for these by:

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

If that returns an empty string you will need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with something like this:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`

In something like `/etc/profile`

Source: [Global Emacs configuration](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)